# get all text between bracket but skip nested bracket

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

Im trying to figure out how to get the text between two bracket tags but dont stop at the first closing )

```
__('This is a (TEST) all of this i want') i dont want any of this;
```

my current pattern is `__\((.*?)\)`

which gives me

```
__('This is a (TEST)
```

but i want

```
__('This is a (TEST) all of this i want')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to escape two parenthesis in your regex : `__\((.*)\)`;

Check on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UTgXno/1).

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regex subroutine to match text inside nested parentheses after `__`:

```
if (preg_match_all('~__(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))~', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[2]);
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8wR1MM/1).

**Details**

- `__` - a `__` substring
- `(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))` - Group 1 (it will be recursed using the `(?1)` subroutine):

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)` - Group 2 capturing 0 or more repetitions of any 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` or the whole Group 1 pattern is recursed
  - `\)` - a `)` char.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/icd5O):

```
$s = "__('This is a (TEST) all of this i want') i dont want any of this; __(extract this)";
if (preg_match_all('~__(\(((?:[^()]++|(?1))*)\))~', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[2]);
}
// => Array ( [0] => 'This is a (TEST) all of this i want'  [1] => extract this )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pattern `__\((.*)?\)`.

The `\` escapes the parentheses to catch literal parentheses. This then captures all the text inside that set of parentheses.